# c#.net using asp:CompareValidator with dates

Tags: c#, .net, date, validation

I have dates generated by a Javascript enhanced textbox in the format dd/mm/yyyy, which when validated with a asp:comparevalidator fails to to validate correctly.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator4" runat="server" 
                      ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" ValueToCompare="txtStartDate" 
                      Display="None" 
                      ErrorMessage="End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date." 
                      Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="True">    
</asp:CompareValidator>

<strong>Start Date</strong><asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Width="215px" CssClass="textfield" Style="width: 176px; margin-left:5px;"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<strong>End Date</strong><asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Width="215px" CssClass="textfield" Style="width: 176px;  margin-left:5px;"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

In case it isn't clear I want the date in txtStartDate to be earlier than the one in `txtEndDate`.

When validated, I get gibberish results with no obvious pattern to when the validation fails. Can anyone see what is wrong?

btw I am aware of how poor the html is - I am editing someone else's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the page's culture to `en-GB`?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_Default" Culture = "en-GB" %>
```

Found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ptahiliani/archive/2009/07/04/how-to-use-compare-validator-with-ddmmyyyy-format-of-date.aspx).

**Update** You have a bug in your validator markup. If you want to compare  both textbox-dates with each other you have to provide  the `ControlToValidate` and the `ControlToCompare` (not the `ValueToCompare`)

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator4" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" 
    ControlToCompare="txtStartDate" 
    Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
    Display="None" ErrorMessage="End Date should be greater than or equal to Start Date." SetFocusOnError="True">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Hi. I followed your link and tryed a few things, in the process of which I found this line: CompareValidator4.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); in the page_load function which doesn't appear to get updated when the controls are validated. Any idea how to correct this?